# TIWTreeview collapses on selecting item

Tags: delphi, web-applications, treeview, intraweb

I have an intraweb form with a IWTreeview which has code in the ItemClick event. If you expand a node and select a child node, the form refreshes and the node collapses. How can the node be set expanded as it was previously? The issue is nothing to do with what the code is in ItemClick. It is how to get the treeview to remember that the node was open.

Comment: Did you try the vendor support forum?

Comment: news.atozed.com appears to be down.

Comment: There is also https://forums.embarcadero.com/forum.jspa?forumID=93